Gradle dockerfile for springboot project error when I run test
Here's my error:
ApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
80.30     java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
80.30         Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractBeanFactory.java:326
80.30             Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788
80.30                 Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException at SpringLiquibase.java:259
80.30                     Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException at SpringLiquibase.java:251
80.30                         Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException at ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:346
80.30                             Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at Net.java:-2

Here's my dockerfile:
FROM gradle:8-jdk17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY build.gradle.kts ./
COPY settings.gradle.kts ./
COPY settings.gradle.kts ./
#COPY gradle ./gradle
COPY src ./src
RUN gradle build --no-daemon

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

When I build my dockerfile I get the above error. And here's my build.gradle.kts if you want to see it:
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.5"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.24"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.24"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.24"
}

group = "com.delivery"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.3.0")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs.addAll("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Any help would be appreciated. The bizarre thing is I only have an empty test class that came with spring initializer when first generated the project

The error tells you

Liquibase - which is tool that manages the schema of a database is trying to connect to a database, and
That database is Postgres, but the driver cannot connect

Do you have a Postgres server running? and if you so have you defined the connection string?
If you have a local Postgres note that because you are running the application inside Docker, a local Postgres server cannot be access from localhost but must use an IP address to get out of the Docker container.
If you never even intended to have a database, then remove the dependencies of Liquibase and Postgres.

I do have a database running, but I still want to build the docker image without having to connect to the db

Your build is running tests, it would seem, and the one of these tests requires access to a database.  So, you are going either skip all tests, or the DB-needing tests, or use some kind of embedded test database / test container.
